# Is it possible to make only specific parts of a GLTF model clickable using AFrame?

Tags: html, cursor, aframe, gltf

I am loading a GLTF model in AFrame and traversing its nodes using AFrame components. I want to make only some parts of this model clickable i.e. when user hovers on these parts the cursor will be pointer and for all other parts it will be a default cursor.
Is this possible using HTML or Aframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are your friend! Both the [cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/cursor.html#intersection-data) and the [raycaster](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/raycaster.html#events) components expose the intersected object (not only the HTML element, but the underlying mesh as well).

So You can create a [custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar) which will

- check if the mouse is hovering over the model
- keep track of the intersected mesh and apply you logic

Check it out in this example (which i hope is extensively commented):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      // check when the cursor is intersecting with this entity
      this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected", evt => {
        this.intersection = evt.detail;
      });

      // check when the intersection is cleared
      this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected-cleared", evt => {
        this.intersection = null;
      });
    },
    tick: (function() {
      // helper variable to keep track of which element is under the mouse
      var currentMesh = null;

      return function() {
        // if there is no intersection, return
        if (!this.intersection) {
          if (currentMesh) {
            // remove highlight if a mesh was highlighted
            this.highlight(currentMesh, false);
            currentMesh = false;
          }
          return;
        }
        // grab the current intersected object
        var intersection = this.intersection.getIntersection(this.el);
        if (!intersection) return;
        const obj = intersection.object;
        // if nothing was cached, highlight this mesh
        if (!currentMesh) {
          currentMesh = obj;
          this.highlight(currentMesh, true);
        }
        // if a mesh was highlighted, clear the old one, and highlight the new one
        if (obj.uuid !== currentMesh.uuid) {
          this.highlight(currentMesh, false);
          currentMesh = obj;
          this.highlight(currentMesh, true);
        }
      };
    })(),
    highlight: function(mesh, highlight) {
      var color = highlight ? 0xffff00 : 0x000000;
      mesh.material.emissive.setHex(color);
      mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="z-index: 99999; position: fixed; top: 5%; text-align: center">
    <p>
      Model by <a href="https://poly.google.com/view/62zn39CRkbG">google</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
    <a-assets>
      <a-asset-item id="model" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/0c08e4fb-3f49-4a20-bb84-a2eceb70bca4%2FWall_Art_Classical_01.gltf?v=1612251538844"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

    <a-entity position="0 1 -3" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" gltf-model="#model" foo></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

Comment: If you'd like some clarification feel free to comment